# I get an error when using ggsurvplot to plot a survival plot

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am fitting survival plots but I get an error I can't understand when trying to create a plot with ggplot.

I can fit a model with Surv like this to get the whole population.

```
kaplan_fit <- survfit(Surv(censor.time, status) ~ 1, data=survival.dataset)
```

```
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(censor.time, status) ~ 1, data = survival.dataset)

 time n.risk n.event Pr((s0)) Pr(1)
    1     68       0    1.000 0.000
   30     55      13    0.809 0.191
   60     32      23    0.471 0.529
   90     29       3    0.426 0.574
```

But then when I try to plot it like so I get an error

```
ggsurvplot(
  fit = survfit(Surv(censor.time, status) ~ 1, data = survival.dataset), 
  xlab = "Days", risk.table=T,
  ylab = "Overall survival probability")
```

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 56, 0, 112
```

If I change it so the tilde refers to status it works but gives me a plot of status = 1 or 2, like this:

```
ggsurvplot(
  fit = survfit(Surv(censor.time) ~ status, data = survival.dataset), 
  xlab = "Days", risk.table=T,
  ylab = "Overall survival probability")
```

[image]

Can someone help me with why I get this error?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as changing status to numeric

```
survival.dataset$status<-as.numeric(survival.dataset$status)
```

That solved the issue.

Comment: That should be referred to the maintainer of `ggsurvplot` as a serious infelicity. The `ggsurvplot` function should have caught the error and passed the error message from `Surv` that said "Error in Surv(time, status) : 
  Invalid status value, must be logical or numeric"